# Padding disables the submit button

Tags: css, html-table

Following is my HTML for submit button :

```
<div id="header">
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td><h1></h1></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="search" class="search"/>
             <input type="submit" class="search-btn" name="submit" value="Search"/></td>                        
        </tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

And following is my CSS :

```
#header table td .search-btn{width: 60px; margin-left: 5px;                                                          
                             border: 1px solid #D5EA3B;
                             padding: 9px;
                             display: inline-block;
}
```

The issue is when I am trying to add padding it disabling the submit button (non-clickable) and if I am removing the padding then its enabling it (clickable). This is really weird issue. I am not getting whats exactly this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Having just created this code in JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3w4e5/

The issue doesn't exist, please confirm your code is correct

Comment: @Ryan : The code is correct but and by adding padding its working there.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough : But on my side its not working

Comment: This jsfiddle does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/xvsER/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.

So first your CSS isn't quite correct that you pasted, remove the #header table etc..

```
.search-btn{width: 60px; margin-left: 5px;                                                          
                             border: 1px solid #D5EA3B;
                             padding: 9px;
                             display: inline-block;
}
```

So the padding isn't the issue, the border is the issue making it appear that it isn't clicking. If you visit: http://jsfiddle.net/3w4e5/2/ you see that the button works as expected,however  when you re-add the border is appears to be broken.

You will want to create a hover and active version of the button as well:

See: http://jsfiddle.net/3w4e5/3/

**Update:**

See this fiddle for an active & hover CSS versions added in so it shows that the button is hovered and clicked on, your initial CSS make it's so the button doesn't look like it's being clicked but it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/3w4e5/4/

Comment: But if I am removing border then button is looking weird. Is there any solution on this?

Comment: Yes as I said, create a active & hover version of the button with similar css but make it obvious that it being clicked i.e change the background colour slightly. Check out the last fiddle link an

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I found different solution on this instead of hover effect. I applied the `border-color` to button and its working for me. Obviously its not the good solution and button still looking OK but at least its matching with my site CSS and background color. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because, you have added a  `border: 1px solid #D5EA3B;`

**UPDATE**:

The problem is that your td that houses the input type="text" and submit button is overlapping or sitting on top of the Submit. You should divide the second td in to two tds and have input type text in one td and submit button in other.

Comment: @default : But if I am removing border then button is looking weird. Is there any solution on this